# Почему particles js не работает как фон под елементами сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Вот в чём проблема. На скрине видно что фон работает только там где нету елементов.
Я проблему решил. Просто написав на блок position absolute, но верстка сбиваеться. Как сделать так что бы и верстка сохранилась и фон работал?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcu icon" href="photos/logotype.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="particles-js">
    <div class="site">
    <div class="header">
        <img src="photos/logo1.png" class="logo">
            <a href="" class="link">test</a>
            <a href="" class="link">test</a>
            <a href="" class="link">test</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <center><img src="photos/logo.png" class="img"></center>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                <center><a class="text">test</a></center>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="articles">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <center><img src="photos/test.jpg" class="articleimg"></center>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <center><img src="photos/test.jpg" class="articleimg"></center>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <center><a href="" class="articleslink">test</a></center>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <center><a href="" class="articleslink">test</a></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="aboutus"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="particles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
@font-face{
            src:url(fonts/8289.otf);
            font-family: Intro;
        }
        @font-face{
            src:url(fonts/ARLRDBD.TTF);
            font-family: Arial;
        }
        @font-face{
            src:url(fonts/BloggerSans.ttf);
            font-family: BloggerSans;
        }
        body,html{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #particles-js{
            background-color: #232741;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .site{

        }
        .link{
            margin-left: 20px;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family: Arial;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .link:hover{
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        .col{
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0;
            float: left;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .row{
            display: flex;
        }
        .container{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .content{
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .text{
            font-family: BloggerSans;
            font-size: 40px;
        }
        .articleimg{
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .articleslink{
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 25px;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            position: relative;
        }
        .articleslink:hover{
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        .articles{
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
        .img{
            background-image: url(photos/logo.png);
        }
        .aboutus{
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: white;
        }
```

Comment: Уточните Ваш вопрос. У Вас же стоят картинки в данных местах. Если хотите установить фон для всей страницы - используйте `backgound` или `background-image` в css в `body`.  Опишите какого результата Вы хотите добиться.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XF4MSfZx04E как в этом видео. Но если делать как он то получиться то что сейча есть. И данный фон не будет отображаться под элементами. Я хочу сделать так что бы он отображалься.

Comment: возможно, нужчно чтобы `<div id="particles-js"></div>`был не контейнером для всего содержимого, а находился на одном уровне с `<div class="site">`